# components navigation

Tags: java, forms

I put three buttons on my form, the focus is on the first one.
There's no response to the navigation buttons and i can't get to the other two buttons.
There's also no response to the main button (the first button isn't clicked).
I added action listeners and used setNextFocusRight() and nothing works.
What else do I need to do to enable navigation between components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you haven't loaded any theme and all your buttons look the same (white or something). Navigation is working fine, but you can't see the result of pushing DOWN button.

Comment: i've tested and seems ok now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

addMnemonic is what you need i guess. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) I think it will help you ))